# Angular 5 gradient background image

Tags: css, angular

How can I add gradient to an image when using Angular 5 ?

I currently have this:

```
<div class="event-home-img" [style.background-image]="'url(' + event?.eventImage + ')'"></div>
```

If `linear-gradient(url( ... , transparent)` is added, it throws an error because the `linear-gradient` method doesn't exist.

My solution:

```
<div class="event-home-img" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'linear-gradient(transparent 80%,
    #151825), url(' + event?.eventImage + ')'}">
    </div>
```

Comment: try [ngStyle]="{'background-image' : 'linear-gradient(url( ... , transparent)'}"

Comment: @Arash shouldn't that be `[ngStyle]=...` ?

Comment: @deezg yes yes , sorry ( edited )

Comment: great! i would write it as an answer if i were you ;)

Comment: Yeah. It should work, but if I do this `[ngStyle]="{'background-image' : 'linear-gradient( red, transparent)'}"` it works, but when image is set it doesn't show `[ngStyle]="{'background-image' : 'linear-gradient( event?.eventImage, transparent)'}"`

Comment: Wait. I'm not adding url()

Answer (score 3):

**You can use ngStyle**

**here solution**

**html/ template**

```
<div class="myclass" [ngStyle]="setMyStyle()">
  this is background angular backgorund
</div>
```

**In your component**

```
setMyStyle() {
    let styles = {
      'background':'#eb01a5',
      'background-image': 'url("https://getsatisfaction.com/corp/img/product/five_obstacles.png"), linear-gradient(red, yellow)',
      'background-repeat':'no-repeat'
    };
    return styles;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example with url() ? I can't seem to replace red or yellow with an image. From property or hard coded.

Comment: You Can See This Url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gradient-background-image-rfvp86

Answer (score 1):

You can do something which is called `Layer stack`. By simply separating your `background-image` values with a `,` they get stacked.

So this would look like this:

```
<div class="event-home-img" [style.background-image]="'linear-gradient(/* your gradient */), url(' + event?.eventImage + ')'"></div>
```

In this case, `linear-gradient` would be on top of the stack, which means it is in front of the `image`.

Comment: I'm sure this works as well, but I used ng-style. See my edit.

Answer (score -1):

```
[style.background-image]="linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.0)), url('+event?.eventImage+')'"
```

Comment: Missing ' (apostrophe) at the beginning of the string value (linear-gradient)